# How to replace a word in particular cells of a dataframe without changing the same word in other cells in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a 14K rows. I want to replace a few words in  column of my dataframe.

| Bathroom_type |
| --- |
| bath |
| baths |
| sharedbaths |
| privatebath |
| sharedbath |

I want to Replace the words - 'bath', 'baths', and 'privatebath' with "Private Bath" and Replace the words - 'sharedbath' and 'sharedbaths' with "Shared Bath"

I used the below line of code to replace in the cells that contain only bath, but it is replacing the word bath in all the rows, so cell containing 'sharedbath' changed to 'sharedPrivate Bath'.

```
df['bathroom_type'] = df.bathroom_type.str.replace(r'bath', 'Private Bath')
```

Please help me to fix my problem. thanks. I'm really new to python so please reply an easy way or detailed explanation of the correct coding.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the list of unique words in the column `Bathroom_type`

Comment: r'^bath$' indicates start and end of word before and after bath, that excludes the cases you don't want, and still use replace method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `map` every value in `'bathroom_type'` column as explain [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

*"Used for substituting each value in a `Series` with another value, that may be derived from a function, a dict or a `Series`"*.

```
r_words = {'bath' : "Private Bath",
           'baths' : "Private Bath",
           'privatebath' : "Private Bath",
           'sharedbaths': "Shared Bath",
           'sharedbath': "Shared Bath"}

df['bathroom_type'] = df['bathroom_type'].map(r_words)
```

Comment: bath and baths are missing in your dictionary...

Comment: It is already corrected, although the best could be to use a method without a ```dictionary```.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. i was stuck at this for so long. Can you please explain me how lambda works? i mean can you pls explain me this code for my learning. thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `map`, not `apply`: `df['bathroom_type'].map(r_words)`